# Prometheus statistic query

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I'm trying to do blackbox monitoring with prometheus-grafana-alertmanager-blackbox_exporter.
There is my problem:
I have many instance in a cluster. So I labeled it like

> probe_success{cluster="cluster-1", instance="instance-1"}
>
> probe_success{cluster="cluster-1", instance="instance-2"}

Now I just want to count that in range last 30m, how many time probe_success metric on cluster-1 return value 1 or 0.
Prometheus really can not do this thing ? I can't find any doc or question about it

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called [aggregation over time](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time). In your case, it would be the sum of the metric over the las 30 minutes:

```
sum_over_time(probe_success[30m])
```

Note that what you are computing is hard to act upon because it depends on the number of scrapes in the last 30 minutes. The reason is that if the exporter or Prometheus was down (meaning no metrics produced) or if you change the scrape interval in Prometheus, the meaning of the value will change.

It is usually better to use `avg_over_time` to represent the percentage of time the application was measurably up in the last 30 minutes.